# What is the word for the relationship between a function and another the it can be tranformed into

Tags: terminology

Given a function $f(x)$ and another function $g(x)$ such that $g(x)=a×f(b×(x-c))+d$ for some numbers $a$,$b$,$c$, and $d$, is there a name for how they are "basically" the same?

Comment: "Equivalent up to linear transformations of domain and range"?

Comment: Sounds right! Thank you!